# Zabbix: Error: Cannot add host

Tags: database, zabbix

I am trying to add a new host to Zabbix and getting this error:

[image]

I have unsuccesfully searched for this host a04sql005 using the global search and latest data.  I can see the host though in the mysql database in the hosts and interface tables.

How can I safely remove this host that is invisible to the Zabbix Interface?

Version: Zabbix 2.4.7

Update: 10:55am

[image]

Comment: Please post the "hosts" table entry for that host.

Comment: @Richlv question updated

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the host via Zabbix API using the host id

Small python sample:

```
from zabbix.api import ZabbixAPI
zapi = ZabbixAPI(url='http://zabbixServer/zabbix/', user='admin', password='zabbix')
zapi_result = zapi.host.delete(14240)
```

You have to install py-zabbix first! (`pip install py-zabbix`)

Comment: Thanks Simone, I will try this out.

Comment: Hi Simone, turned out to be a permissions issue. Thanks for the assist anyway.